# iAd banner loads then immediately unloads

Tags: ios, iad

I'm seeing a strange behavior when using an iAd banner.

On the `bannerViewDidLoadAd` callback, I add the `bannerView` as a subview to main view to display it.

For the `didFailToReceiveAdWithError` callback, I remove the bannerView from the main view and release/nil the reference and delegate to the banner view. I do this as I have other ad networks that I load if/when iAd fails (similar to AdWhirl but implemented in house).

The scenario I encounter is that *sometimes* `didFailToReceiveAdWithError` is called immediately  after `bannerViewDidLoadAd`, which causes the banner to load and then immediately unload.

It's difficult to reproduce, but it seems to happen when banner view is allocated the first time vs. auto refreshing on its own.

Has anyone else encountered this before and can offer insights?

Answer (score 0):

If your app is still in development then this is normal behavior.... The simulator will purposely send problems to your iAD in your app, so you can test how your app handle's them.

> To assist you in validating your implementation, the iAd Network occasionally returns errors to test your error handling code. You can also test your error handling support manually by turning your device’s wireless capability off.
>
> iAd Network automatically displays the correct ad depending on the how your application binary was downloaded onto your test device, as shown in Table 4-1.

Check it out here: [Apple iAD Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/iAd_Guide/TestingiAdApplications/TestingiAdApplications.html)

Comment: Are you sure this is the case?

Comment: @user3072558 I believe that means you are not catching the error correctly.

Comment: When I test in the simulator, iAd does occasionally fail (like when it has no inventory), and then I move on to the next ad network, which is the expected behavior.

The behavior I'm seeing is that iAd reports that it successfully loaded, the ad banner displays for a brief second, and then iAd reports failure, and the banner gets unloaded. 

I find the second case strange. Since iAd is basically a black box, there's no real way to tell what kind of error scenarios it generates. The documentation doesn't really say either.